# If $Y = X^2$, how do I find $P\{Y = 1\}$ to compute $E[X^2]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable taking on any of the values $-1,0,1,$ with probabilities $P\{X= -1\} = 0.2,$ $P\{X= 0\} = 0.5,$ $P\{X= 1\} = 0.3.$ Compute $E[X^2]$.

I start off letting $Y = X^2$, then finding pmf of $Y.$ While I know $P\{Y = 0\} = P\{X= 0\} = 0.5,$ how do I find $P\{Y = 1\}$?

Comment: Well, if $X^2=1$, what might $X$ be?

Comment: Another way of expressing the idea behind @lulu's comment is: Other than $Y = 0$, what other values can $Y$ take on.  In general, if a variable $Z$ is constrained by $Z \in \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\},$ and if $p(v_k)$ denotes the probability that $z = v_k,$ then the $\sum_{k=1}^n p(v_k)$ must $= 1.$

Answer (score 1):

If you know $X^2 = 1$, then you also know $X = \pm 1$. So, you have

$$ P[Y = 1] = P[X^2 = 1] $$
$$ = P[X = 1 \cup X = -1] $$
$$ = P[X = 1] + P[X = -1] - P[X = 1 \cap X = -1] . $$

Assuming $X = 1$ and $X = -1 $ are mutually exclusive, you have

$$ P[Y = 1] = P[X = 1] + P[X = -1] . $$

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get $E(X^2)$ is to use the definition of expectation

$$E(X^2)=\Sigma_i x_i^2p(x_i)=(-1)^2\cdot 0.2+0^2\cdot 0.5+1^2\cdot 0.3=0.5$$

---

Edit: answering to comment of @Prasus Biswas here is a definiton of Expectation taken from one of the reference text (Mood Graybill Boes)

[image]

Comment: That is not a definition but a theorem: see [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). I think OP does not want to use that result but use the _actual_ definition that treats $g(X)=X^2$ as another RV with its own probability distribution.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : it's a definition! see my edits with reference of a reputable source. To use this definition for the posted exercise simply substitute $g(X)=X^2$

Comment: Yes, it is taught as a definition in many books and even I learned it the first time as a definition but if you think about it, $g(X)$ is also a RV and its expectation _should_ be defined as $E[g(X)]:=\sum_y yP(g(X)=y)$. The assertion that this is the same as $\sum_x g(x)P(X=x)$ is the "law of the unconscious statistician" (dubbed LOTUS). You can find some references in the wiki I linked: for example, this is theorem 4.1.1 in page 213 of Probability and Statistics 4th Ed (Pearson Education) by DeGroot, Schervish

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : I also know LOTUS. My comment literally said "it's a definition!" I did not write "It is not a theroem"...on the contrary you wrote "That is not a definition but a theorem"... :)